# How to remove space gap when using & symbol in vim

Tags: linux, vim, substitution

I want to add "caps" at the end of all words ending with "w".
For example "jaw" should become "jawcaps", and "blow" should become "blowcaps"

The following command is using regular expression for achieving upper requirement.

```
:%s/[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]*w[^A-Za-z]/&caps
```

But when I use the command above "jaw" converts into "jaw caps" not "jawcaps"

How can I remove the space which is located between "jaw" and "caps"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in your regex, **your regex would match a non character after the value** `w`. In your case, match `jaw[one space]` instead of `jaw`

```
:%s/[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]*w[^A-Za-z]/&caps
                       ^^^ here match a space
```

I suggest you to use a capture regex.

```
:%s/\([A-Za-z][A-Za-z]*w\)\([^A-Za-z]\)/\1caps\2
```

A better solution should be using [look behind](http://ssiaf.blogspot.ru/2009/07/negative-lookbehind-in-vim.html).

```
:%s/\w\w*w\w\@!/&caps
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
:%s/w\>\zs/caps/g
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far, but it would be improved by a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Sato Katsura's answer `:%s/w\>\zs/caps/g` works like this:

1. Search for every place where a "w" character is the last character of a word: `/w\>`.
2. But don't match that "w": only a zero-width space after the "w" should be matched: `/w\>\zs` (or `/w\zs\>`).
3. Replace that match with the word "caps": `s/w\>\zs/caps/`.
4. Do so on every line: range is `%`, and on every occurrence on those lines: flag is `g`.

Putting it together: `:%s/w\>\zs/caps/g`.

- match word end `:h /\>`
- set match start `:h \zs`
- substitution command `:h :s`
- range specification `:h :range`
- substitution flags `:h :s_flags`